# Smallworld: Can I conquer regions occupied by my own In Decline token?

Tags: small-world

I want to conquer a region featuring a Cavern (since I have Underworld as my special Ability). But this region is already occupied by my Amazon token, which is currently In Decline.

Can I do this or is it an illegal move?

Answer (score 15):

From the [rules](https://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_2015_en.pdf), p4:

> **Note:** A player may choose to conquer a Region occupied by
>   his own In Decline token, if he wishes to.